# Replace dots in the property name but not in the property value

Tags: bash, shell, sed, awk, properties-file

I have a file with the following content (it's a `.properties` file from java):

```
product.company.url=http://www.example.com/
product.version=1.3.2
```

I need to replace all dots in the property name, but not in the property value. So, my desired output would be:

```
product_company_url=http://www.example.com/
product_version=1.3.2
```

I have tried `sed -r 's/\.(\w+)([^=]*)/_\1\2/' product.default.properties` but this only replaces the first dot. I think I might have to use lookaheads or lookbehinds, but I don't know if it's possible because the length of the assertion would be variable. Also there may be a variable number of dots in the property name.

Is it possible to do this with a one-liner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this line:

```
awk -F= -vOFS="=" 'gsub(/\./,"_",$1)+1' file.properties
```

test with your example:

```
kent$  echo "product.company.url=http://www.example.com/
product.version=1.3.2"|awk -F= -vOFS="=" 'gsub(/\./,"_",$1)+1'
product_company_url=http://www.example.com/
product_version=1.3.2
```

Comment: That is perfect! Thank you very much (I cannot accept the answer yet, will do it in 10 minutes)

Comment: @jvallver my answer may solve your problem. however I would say that, the naming convention of prop name in java properties file is with "dot", not underscore.

Comment: I know, but I'm having trouble with Jenkins interpreting properties with dots in their names using the EnvInject plugin. I'm trying this as a workaround in one concrete build, but usually I'm using dot-separated properties :)